# Gateway ML3109 only boots with "acpi=off"

Tags: lubuntu, acpi

I have a Gateway ML3109 that I have installed Lubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64 bit on. I used the alternate installer, and the acpi=off option during the install. My system will only boot with the parameter "acpi=off". This has also created another problem, my laptop will not shut down, I have to do it manually. I am worried about the temperature of my system. How can I configure acpi to work properly? Or, how can I tell if my system is acpi compatible?